# Python Openpyxl Parse function identifies RANGE incorrectly

Tags: python, openpyxl

My program is supposed to take each cell with a formula in the worksheet and "explode" it. This means it parses the excel formula and replaces each cell reference (each RANGE, ie A22) with the value of that cell surrounded by parenthesis. So if excel cell `A22=A3*A5`, and cell `B10` **value is** `=A22+10`, `B10` becomes = `(A3*A5)+10`. The program then keeps looping and replacing the cell values until they're just raw numbers and functions.

This works well until until the program gets to a particular cell in the excel file I'm working on, `C34`.

```
C34=IF(B1_Data,IF(B1_Suf,IF(B1_05,BD34,""),IF(AND(B2_Data,B1B2_Suf),IF(B1_05,BD34,""),BD30)),BD29)
```

The first and second iteration goes well...

```
'C34_lvl0': 'IF($BA$29,IF($BA$31,IF($BA$33,BD34,""),IF(AND($BA$30,$BA$32),IF($BA$33,BD34,""),BD30)),BD29)'

'C34_lvl1': 
'=IF((NOT(OR(I29="",I30="",I31="",I31=10.0001,I32=""))),IF((AH32<0),IF((AND(#REF!>0,#REF!<0.5)),(LD-ddTaq MASS TOO SMALL - INCREASE BUILD SIZE),""),IF(AND((NOT(OR(I36="",I37="",I38="",I38=10.0001,I39=""))),(AH39<0)),IF((AND(#REF!>0,#REF!<0.5)),(LD-ddTaq MASS TOO SMALL - INCREASE BUILD SIZE),""),(INSUFFICIENT LD-ddTaq TO SUPPORT BUILD, USE 2ND BATCH))),(ENTER ACTUAL LD-ddTaq POLYMERASE VALUES FOR LOT #1))
```

But then I get the below error with the next iteration. When I parse the above (lvl1) formula, I see it is showing `(NOT(OR(I29="",I30="",I31="",I31=10.0001,I32="")))` as a *single range*. This does *not* happen in other excel IF functions.

Anyone know what is going on or a work around? Is this a bug? I'm using openpyxl version **2.4.9** and python **3.6.4**

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\20180818HW_ValidationAid_v016.py", line 186, in <module>
    tok=Tokenizer(tFinal) #dissect each cell, do the spiel
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formula\tokenizer.py", line 53, in __init__
    self._parse()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formula\tokenizer.py", line 86, in _parse
    self.offset += dispatcher[curr_char]()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\formula\tokenizer.py", line 157, in _parse_error
    (self.offset, self.formula))
openpyxl.formula.tokenizer.TokenizerError: Invalid error code at position 402 in '=IF((NOT(OR(I29="",I30="",I31="",I31=10.0001,I32=""))),IF((AH32<0),IF((AND(#REF!>0,#REF!<0.5)),(LD-ddTaq MASS TOO SMALL - INCREASE BUILD SIZE),""),IF(AND((NOT(OR(I36="",I37="",I38="",I38=10.0001,I39=""))),(AH39<0)),IF((AND(#REF!>0,#REF!<0.5)),(LD-ddTaq MASS TOO SMALL - INCREASE BUILD SIZE),""),(INSUFFICIENT LD-ddTaq TO SUPPORT BUILD, USE 2ND BATCH))),(ENTER ACTUAL LD-ddTaq POLYMERASE VALUES FOR LOT #1))'
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the tokeniser.

Comment: Thank you for replying! That's what I was afraid of. I'm pretty new to python and coding in general. I'll try putting it on the Bitbucket for openpyxl and see if anything happens. Would you know if there is anything I can add to the Bitbucket issue that would help identify this problem? (other than the above)